# how to http request with Lua when Nginx start and restart

Tags: nginx, lua, openresty, lua-ngx-module

I am using Lua Nginx [module](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module) in my nginx server.

I have a Lua script which is execute by `init_worker_by_lua_file` in nginx.conf so the script will execute when nginx start and restart.
What the Lua script does is, it request rest api to some server and just retrieve the response.

In this case, I use curl for access the api, is there any way without using curl?

I already try `ngx.location.capture` and `ngx.exec` those are not work for `init_worker_by_lua_file`

Comment: Maybe a workaround using `ngx.timer.at(0, ...)` described [here](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#cosockets-not-available-everywhere) will be suitable for you?